# Associate an arbitrary type with another

Tags: typescript

This is sort of a loaded question, and I'm not quite sure how to simplify it any more than what I have.

I'm trying to provide additional type information within a function call. I've devised a way to wrap up some pre-defined interfaces with Generic types in order to provide meta information which is used to retrieve instances of the interfaces.

These interfaces are pre-defined raw types which the end-user (developer) will be working with:

```
interface Player {
  name: string
  age: number
  id: string
}

interface Team {
  name: string
  color: string
  player1: Player
  player2: Player
}
```

Here are the types that I came up with:

```
type MyObjectWrapper<T> = { _metaInfo: string } & { 
  [P in keyof T]: 
    T[P] extends string | number | boolean | any[] ? MyPrimitiveWrapper<T[P]> : MyObjectWrapper<T[P]>
}

type MyPrimitiveWrapper<T> = { _metaInfo: string }
```

Using these types, I am able to defines constants which are what will be used in the library I am working on. Basically, the developer will use these constants to get the information they need from the 3rd party API. Here is an example constant:

```
const theTeam: MyObjectWrapper<Team> = {
  _metaInfo: "theTeam",
  name: { _metaInfo: "team name" },
  color: { _metaInfo: "team color" },
  player1: {
    _metaInfo: "player1",
    name: { _metaInfo: "player1 name" },
    age: { _metaInfo: "player1 age" }
  },
  player2: {
    _metaInfo: "player2",
    name: { _metaInfo: "player 2 name" },
    age: { _metaInfo: "player 2 age" },
  }
}
```

All of these properties are exported and exposed to be made available to pass into `get()` and `set()` functions. Currently, the user is able to call `get()` with this constant just fine.

```
function get<T>(propOrObj: MyObjectWrapper<T> | MyPrimitiveWrapper<T>): T {
    // Do some stuff with a 3rd party API which gets a valid T object
    // This function uses _metaInfo as the argument to the 3rd party API which returns T
    return {} as T
}

const teamColor = get(theTeam.color) // returns type "string"
const wholeTeam = get(theTeam) // returns type "Team"
const player1Age = get(theTeam.player1.age) // returns type "number"
```

The issue arises when needing to set some information about an object or property. For example, the user cannot simply pass in a whole team object into the `set()` function. They are required to pass in an object containing `name: string` or `color: string` or both.

I would like to set function to enforce the setting type of an object, but I'm not sure how to associate this setting type with what I have already. Here is an example set function which works, but does not provide type information about what is expected:

```
function set<T>(propOrObject: MyObjectWrapper<T> | MyPrimitiveWrapper<T>, newValueToSet: any): T {
  // Call out to 3rd party to set 
  // return the newly mutated object
  return {} as T
}

// Should compile:
const changedTeam = set(theTeam, { name: "NewTeamName", color: "red "})
// or
const changedTeam = set(theTeam, { name: "NewTeamName" })
// or
const changedColor = set(theTeam.color, "red")
const changedPlayer1 = set(theTeam.player1, { id: "newId" })
const changedPlayer1_2 = set(theTeam.player1, { name: "Bob", age: 30 })

// Should not compile:
const changedTeam_2 = set(theTeam, { player1: { name: "Bob", age: 30 } })
const changedColor = set(theTeam.color, { "red" })
const changedPlayer1_3 = set(theTeam.player1: { name: "Bob", id: "newId" })
// Player can only be set with an ID or with name and age
```

1. Where do I define this extra type information about myTeam and its properties so that `set()` can correctly prompt the expected type given `theTeam` being passed in as the first argument?
2. Is this possible with the structure I currently have?
3. Is there anything I currently have that is bad practice?

[Link to playground with additional explanation in comments.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=71&ssc=72&pln=65&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsFMGdtAQwE4IC4E8AOdRdQLQAm0AZgJYB20RAdBDBkqnsgPYBu5JRoARk0SgAzMl5YUmUAEEACgEkAsACgqaaMlKIAxglkAbRBg2gA3itChKiALbQAXKFhpkVAOYWkbh1YCuNvg0VAF8VFTUNLV0IaFszT2s7R2dXSg9lS202fTZkZJd3TyxDY2QARkcDIyCMvBKNACZK%20uQQsOUQBjgEFAQAd2RELBxkUEwcWFA%20yHJtSCnyfX1%20BF94XjQ2UG1URHVttkpnREo0SfbxhABZDAB5PgAraG00AHVB4Y0AHnAAPlAALxmUAAfTsaEQ8kopDY%20VSblAwVAADJgZ4ANqyUBUUAAa2gGDYpAgAF1HJ5LOBMSTQNAAB7qShESYpdygAA%20fgCJk5fDY2VilA5SEoGHRNIA-KAbrJXDZyGhyBxoO8hiMftT-o4bvcni9VZ9kBrZCTfm1lCpLtKMLLyPLFcqDeq-oDgWDoBCoTC4WzQhaOmAoORJsGRbS6bZiggskcIacpjM5gsliskBxEItEHx9AgcWgYKB9OQ%20INkBh6NJQCRlTkRsnlpBEMqkHUPZBckIiQdYyczmMtnN%20fAVJ1SOwbP3U1mc5PvGgxgXYDhtOQKDRsdDcjY9uRDrR2iOwAAifPQcCxGxH7GTIQx47x6azean0BrEzaE5OZerpibUBz%20goFWeBRg-IUJFgEMhXzUM2EeZ551yEUmC7BVJnwNgRkVXBDxFDYCznUBSF8SgXl3IU%20kWZYiC2F8%20lyXE8NAVA0F8ZBoILell3UDZsGgFQ73nU9z1sbU7ng-UPmdC9-iBcxandT1N0cE8YBEy8ABoElsHxTFBcFIWU0ATwvKwdKvYItNqLIcjyN0DK9WFjPUOIbNyCyrMsYpqnKRx5MsSxFMM71jO80oyiPTyAsSXT9I9YKnKPMKNDKMy7A8ikvFioLHJU5LyiyizPEsooWiaeJakChyjKSsrIsymK-LipSQtqnzQAaNLoAyyqsqanKavyjrCsRKK-T9XCg0mQjiNIxVDimBjYHsFRZrIha5x%20X4AAoMKwW5kF1MTdQQp1vhdTkZTlBUlRVKTzt%20ABKRxwAqgLQE6AARLZYDYOwnFY0hiUo-MW1EcRJCYOR5ATJ9-w9G9QHTIteFeuC9TQTLOimoiSPWoU30mAaYSQSYXxQNx-GgeM-xfcG8EhmQFFhpMWLYo4IEytn2LMJFEEmcBzQEw5nDGC8AGFsiQoE5224SL1oNzkEe4XYwTAV1NdWX5dsFX-U6cWcxQfRfxgFhQ0oLYuKLFd5yoe9FR3BauyEI91KPeh5DtyY7FQE2WxSXwXjYhBueoXgBAXBBocmxtvYTJgFWvMMIk0HR%20P1wMCwKbRGNDfM9gXUMqBhZBt3moV6WDPs2F8O2OOj5nqaILA2DUJik7A1MbDrvZ1xB%20Z4DQbbHu2RAllgfcA1AGG%20l7SdAiQbN0C2O0ozseMhCHkfcbm8iF0L%20jkFxSYB6j0ATpeJjbXtW6pnu5BJhhxtm3H3YiAwWPQyH3f8acdtfD6F4NwWISxE7QhMGOP658KCP3nBTKmD447nzVK4PuSNx6%20AQKXc%208AYy8AQRvecsAAFAJWO0ToAAxJC9JIw5g0lYNg85oDKjLDBNIG5z5uwvFeLui8h6AQLPlSYfDoyNjSDQBhfA67nyVkxGKY8hSBCnp0V4MAG6vhAmPCeTgPQ7xOBDSCuAcQ2AwOpBhs9a5kKLPiGBeMK6TlgL4Nw3hRbk2GOwfA5B0GXG2rAUeBd4EsHHjkPoNB2hrQcUPLau1PEHUvmgY6Ek3gPy2sKK6dobqOlSX8Bh1A%20gADVMFnjYAAZQ9I4E4GBnoQDeh9MA4sQmgFrkJLY9MJDICkH%20H%20nhOhh3Pvk-2PcIQ8Wackzw-TTB8wFkLZQgltjiO8EQTWQJt46xsAwvSjVjIADloB9HUjs8yDClYqVQLwI8wQ9ZfxZKQgh%20hfqLWPkRJCVAiBKm4L4cerBMIaGwstVWot8mS1sq6NZakFZKwYUebMWCjzXOnmowu5d1CP1AGbXMkwKBMjZEIOev4tj81%20iudBKA%20AKlLL%20Pip8FTPgIrdIUgleyT1AJNH6HoWwuQ2aAQkvhFGW3nBBKCLZpgChiHEdGCF6AAE1a6gB7qLIVnCXxWi2TpH0HCkScj0qcgG8JERAA)

Comment: brw add non-working cases to playground

Answer (score 2):

1. Mark the properties you can't change as `readonly`

```
interface Team {
  name: string
  color: string
  readonly player1: Player
  readonly player2: Player
}
```

2. Construct the type you can assign there - a partial copy with omitted readonly keys

```
function set<T>(propOrObject: MyObjectWrapper<T> | MyPrimitiveWrapper<T>, newValueToSet: WritableToWrapper<T>): T {
  return {} as T
}
type Pure<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & unknown
import { ReadonlyKeysOf } from 'type-fest'
type WritableToWrapper<T> =
  | T extends number | string ? T
  : Pure<Partial<Omit<T, ReadonlyKeysOf<T>>>>
```

3. If there are extra limitations to the write type allowed, add them

```
type XOR<T, V> =
  | T & { [K in Exclude<keyof V, keyof T>]?: never }
  | V & { [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof V>]?: never }
type WritableToWrapper<T> =
  | T extends number | string ? T
  : T extends { id: string } ? (
    // if object has ID, allow either only ID or other props
    XOR<{ id: string }, WritableToWrapper<Omit<T, 'id'>>>
  )
  : Pure<Partial<Omit<T, ReadonlyKeysOf<T>>>>
```

https://tsplay.dev/mpQ0gW

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However this doesn't quite work. I have edited my question to add additional constraints in the "should compile" and "should not compile" section. It is more complex than simply allowing certain properties or not.

Comment: @Josh you have the foundation, build whatever you need on top of it. Added the Id requiremend as an example.

Comment: with this example, you've put references to the properties themselves inside the wrapper type.

These types should work for my different objects with various properties names and types. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: Then you can't do this in the way you are trying to, try something else.